# user relationship node access is not working

Tags: views, users

I have enabled the module and tried to work on it. I have created the following users: mtest, emptest, and mdev.
I'm using the Views module to show the nodes. The nodes posted by emptest should only visible to mtest, but this is not happening, even after using the Node access and Content access module.

How do I restrict this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a view, and trying to constrain the nodes listed in the view to those posted by the currently logged in user, you would use a Contextual filter to accomplish it, not Node access or Content access.

Assuming you are using Drupal 7, edit your view and under *Advanced* add a *Contextual filter*. Select `Content: Author: Uid`, and when the configuration screen comes up, under *When the filter value is NOT available* select *Provide default value* and use the select list to choose *User ID from logged in user*.

Save your view, and it will only list nodes authored by the current user.